# Powershell using @ for excluding multiple files

Tags: powershell

I read a string from a .xml file. It looks like this:

```
<ExcludedFiles>'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'</ExcludedFiles>
```

The variable $exlude will be assigned:

```
$exclude = 'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'
```

And I want to pass it to an array '@' so that it is used in Get-item for "-excelude" parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem $_ -name -exclude $exclude ...
```

But it does not work. Maybe I should escape ","?

It works only with the direct assigment, for example:

```
$exclude =  @('a.txt','b.txt','c.txt')
```

Many thanks for your tips! Best regards

Comment: `I read a string` - a string is not an array, and -Exclude needs an array of individual names. Split it on commas to make it an array of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I made some examples, as you can see it depends on how powershell sees the value, if it is a string it wont work you need to transform it in a array, also dont forget to strip the " or '.

Solution:

```
$exclude = "'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'".Split(',').Replace("'","")
```

Example Output:

```
Example 1 | "'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'"
' a .
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
a.txt                 
b.txt                 
c.txt                 
d.txt                 
e.txt                 
f.txt                 

Example 2 | "'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'".Split(',')
'a.txt' 'b.txt' 'c.txt'
String[] System.Array 
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
a.txt                 
b.txt                 
c.txt                 
d.txt                 
e.txt                 
f.txt                 

Example 3 | 'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'
a.txt b.txt c.txt
Object[] System.Array 
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
d.txt                 
e.txt                 
f.txt                 

Example 4 | @('a.txt','b.txt','c.txt')
a.txt b.txt c.txt
Object[] System.Array 
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
d.txt                 
e.txt                 
f.txt                 

Solution | "'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'".Split(',').Replace("'","")
a.txt b.txt c.txt
Object[] System.Array 
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
String   System.Object
d.txt                 
e.txt                 
f.txt
```

Example Code:

```
cls 

#test setup
New-Item -Path $env:TEMP -Name 'testfolder' -Force -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
$path = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath 'testfolder\' 
@('a.txt','b.txt','c.txt','d.txt','e.txt','f.txt') | % { New-Item -Path $path -Name $_ -Force | Out-Null}

#test code

"
Example 1 | `"'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'`""
$exclude1 = "'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'"
"$($exclude1[0]) $($exclude1[1]) $($exclude1[2])"
$exclude1.GetType() | select Name, BaseType 
$exclude1 | % {$_.GetType()} | select Name, BaseType 
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $exclude1


"
Example 2 | `"'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'`".Split(',')"
$exclude2 = "'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'".Split(',')
"$($exclude2[0]) $($exclude2[1]) $($exclude2[2])"
$exclude2.GetType() | select Name, BaseType 
$exclude2 | % {$_.GetType()} | select Name, BaseType 
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $exclude2

"
Example 3 | 'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'"
$exclude3 = 'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'
"$($exclude3[0]) $($exclude3[1]) $($exclude3[2])"
$exclude3.GetType() | select Name, BaseType 
$exclude3 | % {$_.GetType()} | select Name, BaseType
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $exclude3 

"
Example 4 | @('a.txt','b.txt','c.txt')"
$exclude4 = @('a.txt','b.txt','c.txt')
"$($exclude4[0]) $($exclude4[1]) $($exclude4[2])"
$exclude4.GetType() | select Name, BaseType 
$exclude4 | % {$_.GetType()} | select Name, BaseType
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $exclude4

"
Solution | `"'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'`".Split(',').Replace(`"'`",`"`")"
$exclude = "'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'".Split(',').Replace("'","")
"$($exclude[0]) $($exclude[1]) $($exclude[2])"
$exclude.GetType() | select Name, BaseType 
$exclude | % {$_.GetType()} | select Name, BaseType
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $exclude
```

Comment: Hello, many thank for your good examples! this solution works very well. Best regards